# Mouse Event - Mouse not moving as intended

Tags: c#, mouse, hotkeys

I'm trying to move my cursor with Keyboard Arrow Keys. The result is that it will move, but only upwards and left.. towards the top left corner of the screen. It doesn't move downwards as intended.

Now, if I make my xSpeed and ySpeed greater than 3, it will work, but moving downwards and to the right will be slower. If I make the speed 10, then the result will be unnoticable, but that is way too fast for what I need this for.

```
        [DllImport("User32.dll",EntryPoint = "mouse_event",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    internal static extern void Mouse_Event(int dwFlags,int dx,int dy,int dwData,int dwExtraInfo);

    [DllImport("User32.dll",EntryPoint = "GetSystemMetrics",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    internal static extern int InternalGetSystemMetrics(int value);

private void UpdateLoop()
    {
        if (_hotKeys.Contains(Keys.Up))
            MoveCursor(y: -YSpeed());
        if (_hotKeys.Contains(Keys.Down))
            MoveCursor(y: YSpeed());
        if (_hotKeys.Contains(Keys.Left))
            MoveCursor(x: -XSpeed());
        if (_hotKeys.Contains(Keys.Right))
            MoveCursor(x: XSpeed());
    }

private void MoveCursor(int x = 0, int y = 0)
    {
        int to_x = MousePosition.X + x;
        int to_y = MousePosition.Y + y;

        int screenWidth = InternalGetSystemMetrics(0);
        int screenHeight = InternalGetSystemMetrics(1);

        int mic_x = (int)Math.Round(to_x * 65536.0 / screenWidth);
        int mic_y = (int)Math.Round(to_y * 65536.0 / screenHeight);

        Mouse_Event(0x0001 | 0x8000, mic_x, mic_y, 0, 0);
    }
```

In this case, XSpeed and YSpeed are equal one.

```
        public int XSpeed()
    {
        return int.Parse(tb_x.Text);
    }

    public int YSpeed()
    {
        return int.Parse(tb_y.Text);
    }
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: You can use `Cursor.Position` to move the cursor on screen. Suppose your calculated offset is Point `p`, you can set it with `Point cursorPosition = Cursor.Position; cursorPosition.Offset(p); Cursor.Position = cursorPosition;`. You don't need `InternalGetSystemMetrics` because `Cursor.Position` cannot move the cursor outside the boundaries of the current screen.

Comment: Hey, I tried this -- however the application I'm using this on cannot detect that as actual input. My above code is usable, but works incorrectly.

Comment: Do you mean that the application is not in foreground? I.e., that it needs to move the mouse pointer without having the focus? Are you using RegisterHotkey to get the keys pressed?

Comment: I'm doing this for a game, so that I can navigate with keys instead of a mouse. It I'm not sure what input it requires, but your method doesn't get detected.